# Running exe with xml parameter

Tags: c#, xml

I have SqlXml parameter and I would like to send it as argument to my console application.
How can I do that?

```
public static void p_createExcel(SqlString procName, SqlString fileName, SqlString filePath, SqlXml xmlParams, out SqlBoolean result)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process installProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    //settings up parameters for the install process
    installProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"d:\Documents\Temp\console1\createReport.exe";
    installProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    installProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = xmlParams//this doesn't work
    installProcess.Start();

    installProcess.WaitForExit();
    result = (installProcess.ExitCode == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: You have two ways in my opinion. First: you could save your string to file and pass filename to your console app. Second: you could open the exe and send your string to exe input stream...

Comment: Is `createReport.exe` also a .NET application?

Comment: @IdanArye: this is not important, 'cause arguments can be passed to every application!

Comment: @Marco True, but if it's a .NET application, it can be opened as [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and some method other than `Main` can be invoked - one that accepts the `SqlXml`(or `XmlDocument`. Or `XDocument`) directly.

Comment: Currently I'm saving a file and passing a file name as argument(which is unique since more than one concurrent user can execute this assembly).
But @Marco suggestion sounds as a much better idea. (since between saving  a file and opening it in exe application can error happened and file will remain on disk).
Yes, EXE is console application in net.
Do you have some example how to call some other method from assembly and pass sqlXml parameter. Is this possible with System.Diagnostics.Process?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `SqlXml` object to send as the arguments:

```
installProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = xmlParams.Value;
```

Although, as @Marco pointed out this can result in (somehow) unpredicted behavior. To make things more elegant, you could try this:

1. Save the `Value` of your `SqlXml` object into a file (See [`Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to always create a new file).
2. Change your application (*createReport.exe*) to accept file names as input
3. Pass the file name to your process

   `installProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "path to newly created xml file";`

Comment: Probably that string contains " and so various parts of the string would be splitted in different arguments... I think this could be a problem, not counting if string contains CR too...